# Expo Show AsyncStorage data After restarting the app

Tags: reactjs, sqlite, react-native, expo, asyncstorage

I am using expo version 32. On my login screen i set AsyncStorage like:

```
await AsyncStorage.setItem('@MyApp:user', '1');
```

Above code runs when API return true on given credentials. In App.js by using react navigation 2, it redirects to my Landing page.

```
const AppStack = createDrawerNavigator({
    Screen_Landing: { screen: Screen_Landing}
}, {backBehavior: 'initialRoute'});

const AppScreens = createStackNavigator({
    AppStack: { screen: AppStack}
}, {headerMode:'none'})

const AuthStack = createSwitchNavigator({Screen_Login: { screen: Screen_Login}},{headerMode:'none'});

    const MyNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
        {
            AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
            App: AppScreens,
            Auth: AuthStack,
        },
        {
            initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading'
        }
    );
```

Issue is that, When i login successfully it redirects me to landing page but landing page don't gets the AsyncStorage value but when i completely closes the app and re open it then it show the AsyncStorage value. I don't know its issue with expo or react navigation issue. Did anyone have the same issue. I am also having the same issue with my sqlite. If i add something in my sqlite before login & try to fetch data in next screen it also shows nothing but if i closes the app & re opens then it shows data from sqlite. Kindly guide whats the issue.

On my Landing page i am fetching data like:

```
    async componentDidMount() {
    var uid = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MyApp:user')
console.log(uid)
    }
```

Comment: Is your Landing Page already mounted?, the issue might be it is not remounted after `Login` but is mounted after app close, you can put another log statement in `componentDidMount `to verify.

Comment: How are you 'showing' the value?

Comment: In componentDidMount i am calling it like var uid = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MyApp:user')
console.log(uid)

Comment: So, is it not logging(from console.log) the uid?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're trying to render data that is not a `prop` or a `state`.

If you have data coming in after React's initial render, it won't update unless the change is to `state` or `props`.

What you can do is set the user value and your sqlite data to your component's state.

Comment: I am but it set state after i restart app.

Comment: You are setting the data to state or prop? Can you post that code?

Comment: So you are not setting your data to state or calling a handler to change props.  React’s lifecycle on mount is constructor -> render -> componentDidMount. Changes after the initial render that don’t affect state or props aren’t seen.  When you “restart” your app you force a render.  Now changes are reflected.  Like I said above, set it to state.

Comment: No i m not sending data. I set AsyncStorage on Login Screen & just calling AsyncStorage on another screen. I am not passing it via state or props

Comment: And that's why it's not updating your UI.  Re-read my answer and comment above.  Here's the react docs on state https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: I am not setting any state at this stage, i am just fetching data from AsyncStorage..... Kindly check my componentdidmount code